# Why doesn't "pip install" work with Flask and gevent inside a debian docker container?

Tags: docker, flask, debian, pip, gevent

I am trying to build a docker container with flask and gevent, and it is not working as I had hoped.  I can hack it together, but why doesn't pip install work?  Full details below.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

Build container:

```
docker build --pull --no-cache -t flask-test .
```

Run container:

```
docker run -it flask-test /bin/bash
```

Within container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install python-pip
apt-get -y install python-dev
pip install Flask gevent
```

Test:

```
python -c "from flask import Flask"
```

Error:

```
root@2fe825b7f55e:/# python -c "from flask import Flask"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
ImportError: No module named werkzeug.exceptions
```

Try a fix (forget pip):

```
apt-get -y install python-flask
```

Test again. Error:

```
root@2fe825b7f55e:/# python -c "from flask import Flask"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import json, cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 17, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named click
```

Install click, what the heck.

```
pip install click
```

Now it works.

```
root@2fe825b7f55e:/# python -c "from flask import Flask"
root@2fe825b7f55e:/#
```

**EDIT**: I can create a new virtualenv on my macbook, `pip install Flask gevent` and it works fine.  Python version 2.7.9-2+deb8u1 in docker, Python 2.7.10 on my macbook.  Could that be it?

**EDIT 2**: The above commands actually work.  What I really did (that was broken) was:

within container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install python-pip
pip install Flask gevent
apt-get -y install python-dev
pip install Flask gevent
```

So, **don't pip install these without python-dev**!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the `pip install` with the `--process-dependency-links` flag.

You could also try the `--force-reinstall` flag incase that docker image has an old version of Flask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `pip install --process-dependency-links Flask gevent` and `pip install --process-dependency-links --force-reinstall Flask gevent` and I get the same problems. :(

Comment: I found my problem. I kept running pip install before installing python-dev, then installing python-dev. I didn't think it would matter, but it did. I will delete this question soon.

Answer (score 0):

The above commands actually work. What I really did (that was broken) was:

within container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install python-pip
pip install Flask gevent
apt-get -y install python-dev
pip install Flask gevent
```

I thought it didn't matter, and didn't notice, but it did matter.

So, **don't pip install these without python-dev**!